# Should [dotty] and [scala-3] be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation, language-versions

Currently [dotty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotty) and [scala-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-3) are two different tags ("dotty" existed before, "scala-3" is a newly created one). And for each of them "Suggest a synonym" produces "Failed to propose synonym: Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators".

A couple of quotes:

http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/index.html

> Dotty is the project name for technologies that are considered for inclusion in Scala 3

http://dotty.epfl.ch/blog/2020/09/21/naming-schema-change.html

> **Dotty becomes Scala 3**
>
> This article is a heads-up for the upcoming change in the naming of
> Dotty artefacts (as published to Maven). Currently, the organization
> name is “ch.epfl.lamp” which will become “org.scala-lang”. The
> artefact names will be changed from “dotty-xxx” to “scala3-xxx”.
>
> This change will be part of the next Dotty release planned for October
> 1st which will be known as Scala 3.0.0-M1. We encourage maintainers of
> tooling (IDEs, build tools, ...) to prepare for this change now by
> special-casing the way they handle the compiler when its version
> number starts with 3. just like they already had to special-case
> versions starting with 0. to support existing Dotty releases.

***Should "dotty" and "scala-3" be actually the same tag (synonyms)?***

PRO. Mostly, users creating questions tagged with "dotty" or "scala-3" mean the same, namely discussion of new features in Scala.

CONTRA. Dotty is a compiler, Scala-3 is a language (more precisely, a version of language).

PRO. Dotty is the only compiler for Scala-3.

PRO/CONTRA. Dotty is not only the compiler but also the project name.

Possibly related discussion is at https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/migrating-stackoverflow-answers-to-scala-3/3972

Comment: IMO, merging them is probably a good idea.  While yes, the terms aren't *technically* synonyms, the distinction between the compiler and the language is mostly only visible to the folks deeply involved with it.  In my experience, people asking questions are likely to think of the two terms interchangeably.

Comment: As I see it "dotc" is the name of the Scala 3 compiler, where "nsc" is the name of the Scala 2 compiler.  Dotty is the name of the project that became the implementation of Scala 3.  So, yeah merge them / make them synonyms IMO.

Comment: chiming in to agree: as Dale said Dotty is not even the compiler name, it’s the research project that led to Scala 3, so for all intents of purposes they can be conflated into the same tag

Comment: My only concern is that I don't think we don't know for sure yet how `dotty` will be used after Scala 3 releases. Will it go away since the project is complete, or will it continue to be used to refer to the research version of Scala?

Comment: @karlBielefedt, I think future developments will happen incrementally on Scala 3 (there's already been talking about 3.1, 3.2, etc). I don't think the dotty project will keep on being an active research project after it will become Scala 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All new questions should be tagged with [scala-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-3), and there should be a warning if anyone tries to use [dotty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotty). While most previous questions should be retagged [scala-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-3), it's possible some older questions may be left with the [dotty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotty) tag because they refer to a specific version of Dotty when it was still undergoing heavy changes in syntax and semantics.

Here are some questions that perhaps would be better with the [dotty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotty) tag:

- [Run Scala Dotty project using IntelliJ IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51288297/11882002)
- [How to use given in Dotty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59456843/11882002)
- [How does given keyword work in Scala 3 or dotty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59865815/11882002)

While none of these questions or their answers are completely outdated, they can certainly cause some confusion if someone, especially a beginner in Scala, tries to use syntax from, say, Dotty 0.24.0-RC1 in Scala 3.

Answer (score -9):

No, they should not be synonyms.

[dotty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz#Software_architecture) is the editor for the venerable [DOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) graphing language, common in academia but a lot of people has probably also seen it in use in Doxygen.

The tag *dotty* should not have been created as a tag for an internal work-in-progress temporary project 25 years later.

Everything tagged *dotty* today and related to Scala should move to [scala-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-3), leaving [dotty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotty) free for questions about the original tool.

Comment: Can you show examples of questions about Dotty editor at SO? I could find a question where it's mentioned in answer but the question itself was not about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433655/free-visual-editor-for-graph-dot-files There are many questions tagged https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphviz

Comment: I can find one 7 year old question tagged dotty that's not about the scala project. Though once dotty gets released as scala 3 it probably doesn't make a lot of sense to keep the dotty tag around.

Comment: You found a 7 year old question, @Jasper-M? I raise you [this 10 year old question that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770428/calculating-depth-and-descendants-of-tree).

Comment: In that case I found a 10 year old one and wasn't paying much attention.

Comment: What about renaming [dotty] to [dotty-editor]? Then we could create [scala-dotty] and retag. Would solve the problem without any synonyms

Comment: I looked at this some more today and [only one question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdotty%5D+-%5Bscala%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0) is not about Scala. None of them seem to be about the Dotty editor. I'm inclined to retag that one question and just rename this to [scala-dotty]

Comment: `dotty` is a [popular Javascript library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotty) to handle exception-less deep object queries. Although it may be made obsolete by the new optional chaining operator `?.` -- at comment time (Sep 2020) it was getting 24K downloads/week.

Comment: @Paul Can you show examples of questions about this JS library at SO?

Comment: @DmytroMitin From what I can see searching for "[javascript] dotty" primarily yields answers, not questions.